Python MDanalysis package: PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
I'm trying to load my Molecular Dynamics trajectories (.nc Amber file format) into Python using the package MDAnalysis. I'm using the following code:
    clusters = 1085
    list_trajectories = []
    for i in range(clusters):
        list_trajectories.append(os.path.join(path_trajectories, f'cluster_{i}/prod/dry.CL_00.nc'))
    u = Universe(topology, list_trajectories)
    ag = u.atoms

However, this gives me a PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/home/path_to_trajectories/2P49_clusters/cluster_138/prod/dry.CL_00.nc' error (I pasted the whole error message below).
I checked the permissions, and they are the same (-rw-r-----) for cluster_138 as they are for all the other clusters which apparently could be loaded before that number.
Also, the error message isn't always the same:

when I try to load less trajectories (e.g. up until clusters = 400) it works the first time
but when rerunning the same code cell, it fails the second time, even though all variables are reassigned
sometimes it shows the error message for another cluster number (e.g. cluster_490)

So I was thinking it could maybe be a memory issue? But I'm really running out of ideas. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!
The complete error message is:
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)Cell In[8], line 108 for i in range(clusters):9     list_trajectories.append(os.path.join(path_old_trajectories, f'2P49_clusters/cluster_{i}/prod/dry.CL_00.nc'))---> 10 u = Universe(topology, list_trajectories, in_memory=False)

File ~/miniforge3/envs/alessia_spib/lib/python3.12/site-packages/MDAnalysis/core/universe.py:375, in Universe.init(self, topology, all_coordinates, format, topology_format, transformations, guess_bonds, vdwradii, fudge_factor, lower_bound, in_memory, in_memory_step, *coordinates, **kwargs)370 coordinates = _resolve_coordinates(self.filename, *coordinates,371                                    format=format,372                                    all_coordinates=all_coordinates)374 if coordinates:--> 375     self.load_new(coordinates, format=format, in_memory=in_memory,376                 in_memory_step=in_memory_step, **kwargs)378 if transformations:379     if callable(transformations):

File ~/miniforge3/envs/alessia_spib/lib/python3.12/site-packages/MDAnalysis/core/universe.py:580, in Universe.load_new(self, filename, format, in_memory, in_memory_step, **kwargs)577 # supply number of atoms for readers that cannot do it for themselves578 kwargs['n_atoms'] = self.atoms.n_atoms--> 580 self.trajectory = reader(filename, format=format, **kwargs)581 if self.trajectory.n_atoms != len(self.atoms):582     raise ValueError("The topology and {form} trajectory files don't"583                      " have the same number of atoms!\n"584                      "Topology number of atoms {top_n_atoms}\n"(...)588                          fname=filename,589                          trj_n_atoms=self.trajectory.n_atoms))

File ~/miniforge3/envs/alessia_spib/lib/python3.12/site-packages/MDAnalysis/lib/util.py:2553, in store_init_arguments.<locals>.wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)2551             else:2552                 self._kwargs[key] = arg-> 2553 return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

File ~/miniforge3/envs/alessia_spib/lib/python3.12/site-packages/MDAnalysis/coordinates/chain.py:270, in ChainReader.init(self, filenames, skip, dt, continuous, convert_units, **kwargs)268 if dt is not None:269     kwargs['dt'] = dt--> 270 self.readers = [core.reader(filename, convert_units=convert_units, **kwargs)271                 for filename in filenames]272 self.filenames = np.array([fn[0] if isinstance(fn, tuple) else fn273                                                 for fn in filenames])274 # pointer to "active" trajectory index into self.readers

File ~/miniforge3/envs/alessia_spib/lib/python3.12/site-packages/MDAnalysis/coordinates/core.py:82, in reader(filename, format, **kwargs)80     Reader = get_reader_for(filename, format=format)81 try:---> 82     return Reader(filename, **kwargs)83 except ValueError:84     errmsg = f'Unable to read {filename} with {Reader}.'

File ~/miniforge3/envs/alessia_spib/lib/python3.12/site-packages/MDAnalysis/lib/util.py:2553, in store_init_arguments.<locals>.wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)2551             else:2552                 self._kwargs[key] = arg-> 2553 return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

File ~/miniforge3/envs/alessia_spib/lib/python3.12/site-packages/MDAnalysis/coordinates/TRJ.py:446, in NCDFReader.init(self, filename, n_atoms, mmap, **kwargs)443 super(NCDFReader, self).init(filename, **kwargs)445 # ensure maskandscale is off so we don't end up double scaling--> 446 self.trjfile = NCDFPicklable(self.filename,447                              mmap=self._mmap,448                              maskandscale=False)450 # AMBER NetCDF files should always have a convention451 try:

File ~/miniforge3/envs/alessia_spib/lib/python3.12/site-packages/scipy/io/_netcdf.py:247, in netcdf_file.init(self, filename, mode, mmap, version, maskandscale)245 self.filename = filename246 omode = 'r+' if mode == 'a' else mode--> 247 self.fp = open(self.filename, '%sb' % omode)248 if mmap is None:249     # Mmapped files on PyPy cannot be usually closed250     # before the GC runs, so it's better to use mmap=False251     # as the default.252     mmap = (not IS_PYPY)

PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/home/path_to_trajectories/2P49_clusters/cluster_138/prod/dry.CL_00.nc'


path_trajectories is not defined in the example code.  what is it ?

the most common error is to use incorrect relative paths Have you tried an absolute path ?

yes, path_trajectories is an aboslute path... also, the path doesn't seem to be the issue since the code works sometime...

Hello, I am an MDAnalysis developer. Could you consider asking your question in our discussion forum https://github.com/MDAnalysis/mdanalysis/discussions ? Experience shows that there's going to be a lot of back and forth questions/testing and S/O comments are not well suited to having a discussion. By just looking at your code I have no idea why you get a permission error, so there are questions about operating system, software versions, etc. (If we find a solution in our forum then we can update the S/O post with a solution so that anyone here also benefits!)
